# How to reset actionbar in android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, android-actionbaractivity

I have an application with a navigation drawer and some fragments.
In one single fragment I set up a custom action bar: the fact is that when I switch to other fragments the actionbar does not reset (because I call getSupportActionBar() ).
How can I reset the actionBar?
I assume there's a method that allows me to do it.

PS: I don't want to recreate OptionsMenu, I want to reset the entire actionbar.

Comment: What do you want to do change only the `title` in the action bar or the entire toolbar?

Answer (score -2):

If you want to just change the action bar title what you can do is `getActivity.setTitle(yourtitlehere);` 
Here are few codes that you can use to change the entire look of the actionbar as well as the navigationbar

```
getWindow().setNavigationBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.RED));
        toolbar.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.GREEN));
```

But if you want to change the `menu` icons within the fragments you will have to do the following

Use `setHasOptionsMenu(true);` within your fragment `onCreate()` method and then use the `onCreateOptionsMenu()` method and `onOptionsItemSelected()` method

hope it helps

Comment: I tried above solution but if I changes something on actionbar from fragment A, can't be reset, It will keep displaying the changed actionbar on fragment B too.